# Visual Studio 2015 connection to Access 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-access-2016

I can't seem to get my Visual Studio 2015 to connect to Access 2016, both are 64 bit.  I have looked at many forums and most people say to install the MS Access 2010 engine (x64).

I followed the example given here- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893.aspx

When I tried to set up a new data connection through the data connection wizard, your supposed to be able to find using the "Data source" selection dropbox of:

*.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB*

And find in the next dropbox of the OLE DB Provider

*Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB*

However I do not see this option.  I have tried to use some of the other OLE providers in that list and have been able to connect with 1 or 2 of them but then I get an error saying that the tables are invalid objects.  I am lost as to what else to try to be able to connect to any Access db.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue..

As other posts have mentioned, you need the Access DB engine. By having just any version of MS Access is not enough (this is very strange to me).  All of the other posts that I have seen on this topic do not specify WHICH version you need (x86 vs x64).  I am using **Office x64**.

HOWEVER

The Access DB engine I had to use was the **x86 version** (I used Access 2010 db Engine).  I assume this has to do with Visual Studio (2015) being an x86 application but I am not sure.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, since visual studio has only a 32 bit version (for some reason), it can't work with the 64 bit engine. Also, unfortunately, 32 and 64 bit office products cannot co-exist. Now I'm trying to find a solution that won't involve me reinstalling the whole office package...